# Component sizing as3

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a problem when attempting to size a component in a class a few levels down in my app.  The class hierarchy of my app is as follows:

ConcretApp.as --> playlistView.as --> PlaylistGateway.as --> PlaylistState.as --> FLVState.as

When sizing an image to a width of 650 and height of 350 in ConcretApp.as (the main parent class) the size is correct and as expected.  When I try to size an image in FLVState.as these same dimensions are alot bigger.

Does anyone know why?

I have not sized any of these classes in the hierarchy.

Thanks

Christopher Grigg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose resize() is called twice e.g.

```
function resize() {
  ...do resize
  super.resize()
}
```